# Deploying Gatsby to Heroku... .env variables not working

Tags: reactjs, heroku, deployment, environment-variables, gatsby

I'm trying to deploy my Gatsby app with auth0 to Heroku, but it doesn't work like on localhost.

I have the auth0 config in my .env file and all required URLs added to the auth0 dashboard.

To deploy it I added the regarding production URLs in the auth0 dashboard and set the environment variables in Heroku. I tried both `AUTH0_CALLBACK` and `GATSBY_AUTH0_CALLBACK` (for client-side availability), but both didn't work.

To see whether the environment variables are available I added this `process.env`... and on localhost, I can see the variable content here, on the Heroku version there is nothing.

```
const Account = () => {
if (!isAuthenticated()) {
    login()
    return <p>Redirecting to login... {process.env.AUTH0_DOMAIN}</p>
}
```

Does anybody have an idea how to make the environment variables accessible?

Comment: Try REACT_APP_AUTH0_DOMAIN, React env variable needs a prefix

Comment: When you prefixed them with `GATSBY_` have you renamed in both (local & Heroku) environments?

Answer (score 0):

see Heroku config vars - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars - you can set these using either the Heroku CLI or Dashboard.

> Config vars are exposed to your app’s code as environment variables. For example, in Node.js you can access your app’s DATABASE_URL config var with `process.env.DATABASE_URL`.